# Graphql Filter out specific images to not show up?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

My current image component maps through all the images in my folder and displays them, but I want to filter out two of my images so I can apply them to another page instead of displaying on the current page with all the other images in my folder.

How would I write my filter to remove the 2 images from showing up?

I have one image called `background.jpg` and `background-2.jpg` that I want to filter out

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
query {
  allFile(filter: { extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(jpeg)/" },

 // So this line filters out background.jpg, but I can't seem to 
 filter out both background.jpg and background-2.jpg?

  base: {ne: "background.jpg"}
  }) {
    edges {
      node {
        base
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxHeight: 600, maxWidth: 600) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I return a specific image in Gatsby for my reusable component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912058/how-can-i-return-a-specific-image-in-gatsby-for-my-reusable-component)

Comment: no, I ended up using base: {ne: "background.jpg"} and that filtered it out, but I can't seem to get it to work for both background and background-2

Comment: I've already seen those answers and they don't relate to my question because I'm already mapping through my images folder and displaying the images. I need to know how to filter the base filter name "background.jpg" and "background-2.jpg" from not showing up in my page

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the node `name` with `nin` (even another regex) or `ne` rule.

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    allFile(filter: { 
    extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(jpeg)/" } }
    name: {ne: "background"})
     {
      edges {
        node {
          base
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxHeight: 600, maxWidth: 600) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

The query above should do the trick. If not, you can always use `nin` rule to create an array of exceptions or use another regex to exclude the background name.

More information: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter

Comment: it still only filters out background.jpg, but background-2.jpg is still showing up. Is that a naming issue? or how would you filter multiple images based off name?

Comment: I tried putting it in an array `"message": "Expected type String, found [\"background\", \"background2\"]."` but still got this error